# Keep only the year from a data timestamp column

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,3), timestamp = c("20-10-2009 11:35:12", "01-01-2017 12:21:21"), stringAsFactor = FALSE)
```

How is it possible to keep only year in the timestamp column having in mind that all years are after 2000? An expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,3), timestamp = c("2009", "2017"), stringAsFactor = FALSE)
```

Comment: `substr(df$timestamp, 7, 10)`

Comment: sidenote: `stringAsFactor = FALSE` is default since R4.0...

Comment: @Wimpel, it shoudl also be `stringsAsFactor` (plural 's' on strings) for older builds of R, otherwise we are just declaring a new column.

Answer (score 4):

Base R:

```
format(as.Date(df$timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), "%Y")
[1] "2009" "2017"
```

So in the dataframe:

```
df$year <- format(as.Date(df$timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), "%Y")
  id           timestamp year
1  1 20-10-2009 11:35:12 2009
2  3 01-01-2017 12:21:21 2017
```

Another option, if you're into or familiar with regex, is this:

```
sub(".*([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", df$timestamp)
[1] "2009" "2017"
```

Answer (score 2):

See if this answers your question. The code and the output is as follows :-

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,3,4), timestamp = c("20-10-2009 11:35:12", "01-01-2017 12:21:21","01-01-1998 12:21:21"), stringAsFactor = FALSE)
df$timestamp <- dmy_hms(df$timestamp)
df1 <- df %>% 
    filter(year(timestamp) > 2000) %>% 
    mutate(new_year = year(timestamp))
df1

#id           timestamp stringAsFactor new_year
#1  1 2009-10-20 11:35:12          FALSE     2009
#2  3 2017-01-01 12:21:21          FALSE     2017
```

Comment: @Nathalie if you want replace in the same column, change the name of the variable name in the mutate function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not afraid of external packages, one option would be to make use of the lubridate package:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,3), timestamp = c("20-10-2009 11:35:12", "01-01-2017 12:21:21"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::dmy_hms(timestamp)) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(timestamp))
```

Obviously, if you actually want to *replace* the timestampe column, you have to change the last mutate command. Result:

```
 id           timestamp year
1  1 2009-10-20 11:35:12 2009
2  3 2017-01-01 12:21:21 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a tidyverse solution to your problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(id = c(1,3), timestamp = c("20-10-2009 11:35:12", "01-01-2017 12:21:21"), stringAsFactor = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = timestamp %>% 
  str_extract("\\d{4}"))
```

The function `str_extract("\\d{4}")` should always extract the first four digits of your target variable.